# Jquery UI sortable glitches with mouseenter event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, mouseenter

My **sortable** elements have also a **mouseenter** and **mouseleave** event.
When I hover a mouse over it some buttons are being shown on top of sortable element.
While I drag my sortable over another sortable element I have some glitches, those buttons quickly shown and removed within half a second.
If I do drag the **sortables in slow way** I don't have these glitches.

I thought about disable the mouseenter event while I drag the sortable and then turn it on again when it is droped?
Can someone provide an example?
Or maybe any other better solution?

Cheers.

Comment: A [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) replicating your problem would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, and I was able to verify that the error was in the jquery ui css file, when I removed it from the page link, it worked.

Comment: Well, I just removed the "jquery-ui.css" link from my head ... Well I realized that I was not using the style of it, if you are not using the style of it, you can remove it from your header, And then when you perform the drag event it will not automatically call "leave" or "enter", which is correct because you are not leaving the element, just clicked and performed a move action for example. Anyway, if you want the "leave" or "enter" event, then you can use them with more precision ... Any more questions, on the subject?